# Unable to Set default system bottomNavigationBar color in XML, Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-ui, bottomnavigationview

Here is my Music app. The Android system navigation is in white color here,

[image]
..
.
.

but on the same phone other apps like Spotify, it is in black. Like

.
.
.

[image],
How can I make it black when my application is open in Kotlin?

here is the style portion

```xml
  <style name="Theme.Snoozz" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

```xml
<style name="Fullscreen" parent="Theme.Snoozz">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

in manifest activity

```xml
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Snoozz"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

I tried some changes by adding navigation bar color but it didn't change anything,

```
  <style name="Theme.Snoozz" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try different device emulator with different Android versions, because I tried

```xml
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/purple_200</item>
```

And it is working fine:

[image]

So I believe it is a matter of device since some versions don't allow that!